# how to declare a generate protocol as delegate?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

we can make generate protocol like the follow:

```
protocol SomeDelegate {
    typealias T
    func xxx(x: T)
}
```

and make some class conform it:

```
class AA: SomeDelegate {
    typealias T = Int
    func xxx(x: T) {
        // do some thing
    }
}
```

and my problem was how to declare some propert conform to the generate protocol like this:

```
class BB {
    var delegate: SomeDelegate
}
```

the code on above will raise error:

```
Protocol 'SomeDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint 
because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

It Seems I can use the protocol as delegate like follow:

```
class BB {
    var delegate: AA?
}
```

but, this was not I want, it will cause my delegate can't inherit other parent class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use generics, using `SomeDelegate` as a type constraint:

```
class BB <U : SomeDelegate> {
   var delegate: U? = nil
}
```

This way you'll only need to supply the type of `U` when you initialise an instance of `BB`:

```
struct MyStruct : SomeDelegate {
    // The argument of xxx needs to be a concrete type here.
    func xxx(x: Int) {
        // ...
    }
}

let bb = BB<MyStruct>()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can get through this error.

```
protocol SomeDelegate {
    typealias T
    func xxx(x: T)
}
```

Firstly use the proper type class for the function and the compiler infers the type itself.

```
 class AA: SomeDelegate {
    func xxx(x: Int) {
        println(x)
    }
   }
```

Or, you can also override the typealias and assign it the proper type class like,

```
class AA: SomeDelegate {
    typealias T = Int
    func xxx(x: T) {
        println(x)
    }
}
```

And then use it just like the way you have done,

```
class B {
    var someDelegate: AA?
}
```